# Android On Touch

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have been trying to make a program draw circles as I touch the screen with no luck, can anyone please tell me how I can do this? or GOOD tutorial that shows me how... I keep getting errors in my code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import java.lang.Math;

public class GameView extends View{

        private final float x;
        private final float y;
        private final int r;
        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        public GameView(Context context, float x, float y, int r) {
            super(context);
            setFocusable(true);
            mPaint.setColor(0xFFFF0000);
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.r = r;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);
        } 


}
```

GameActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;   
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {    
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_view); 

        main.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent e) {

                 final float x = e.getX();
                 final float y = e.getY();
                  final Handler handler = new Handler() 
                  {                  
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {



                      }                 
                    };          
                    Thread graphicThread = new Thread()       
                    {                        
                        public void run() {                              

                            try {

                                //Do the drop
                                   FrameLayout flView = (FrameLayout) v;
                                 GameView gm = new GameView(getParent(), x,y,25);
                                  flView.addView(gm);


                                     Thread.sleep(1000);

                                     handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                                }
                             catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }                     
                        };                
                         boolean isRunning=true;
                        graphicThread.start();   
                        return true;

                        }           


        }); 


      }
    }
```

Comment: Again as in your last question, you haven't posted the stacktrace.

Comment: I get this

04-12 07:22:48.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1359): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-13
04-12 07:22:48.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1359): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 07:22:48.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:228)
04-12 07:22:48.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1878)
04-12 07:22:48.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at com.beatyourmemory1.game.GameView.<init>(GameView.java:23)

Comment: 04-12 07:22:48.998: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1359):     at com.beatyourmemory1.game.GameActivity$1$2.run(GameActivity.java:44)

Comment: which line is line 23 in your class GameView?

Comment: And line 44 in GameActivity is 
 GameView gm = new GameView(getParent(), x,y,25);

Comment: Casted a close vote. Please try to put a bit more effort into your question. Don't post the entire file. Post only the relevant part of it and of course provide a stack trace from start if something fails. Maybe before even asking that question look at the stack trace yourself and try to figure out what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `getParent()` in your activity if it's not a child Activity.

Use this instead:

`GameView gm = new GameView(this, x, y, 25);`

Answer (score 0):

As the NPE question is already answered, I want to provide an answer for the tutorial question. I have written a series (which is partly updated) which you can find here: I have written a tutorial about 2d graphics for a game. Read this: http://www.droidnova.com/2d-tutorial-series